# How do I get the `ls` to stop showing the "Directory:" header?

Tags: powershell

When I use `ls` it looks like this:

```
__PATH__ >ls

        Directory: __PATH__
```

[image]

I think this is too repetitive and I'd like to remove this extra header from the display, but I have absolutely no idea how defining a `function global:ls` to wrap `Get-ChildItem` lets me do that.

I've investigated further and found that this might have something to do with `Get-FormatData -TypeName System.IO.FileInfo`, but I'm completely ignorant of this formatting mechanism...

Can anyone have any ideas to rescue me from this maze of logic?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74780050/15339544

Comment: Sounds like you'll want to read the [`about_Format.ps1xml` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.4)

Comment: Edit the format file and take it out.